# How to upload files in opensocial 0.9 to an appserver?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, opensocial

Is it possible to upload files in an opensocial app to a remote appserver?
I think of a scenario using *gadgets.io.makeRequest* with the method set to *gadgets.io.MethodType.POST* and pass a file input to the *gadgets.io.RequestParameters.POST_DATA*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current version of the spec, 1.1, it is not possible. Depending upon which container you are using though there maybe some vendor specific functionality which provides this functionality.